How to serve static assets with NestJS and Nginx
I'm serving static assets in NestJS app. Deployed the app in EC2 with PM2 and Nginx (rev. proxy). Everything working fine except static routes giving 404 err. I've configured static assets serving in NestJS & it works fine in the dev & build modes. I think there's an additional setting required in the Nginx for that to work. I'm not sure what is that. Tried Googling it but found no working solution.
My static path looks like https://domain.tld/uploads/sample/9.png
How to make it work?
Edit: PM2 is serving the app in localhost:3000 & the Nginx config is following
server {
    server_name domain.tld;
    
    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        #proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        
        #location /uploads/ { # it doesn't help
        #     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$request_uri;
        #     proxy_redirect off;
        #}
    }

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /certpath/domain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /certpath/domain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = domain.tld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name domain.tld;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

NestJS config
@Module({
  imports: [
    // ...
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'storage'),
    }),
    // ...
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    // ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

Project directory structure
Project
    ├───src
    ├───storage
    │   └───uploads
    │       └───sample
    └───test


hard to say without knowing your nginx config.
my guess is that your nginx config treats /upload/ the same as all other routes, so it tries feeding it to NestJS, who rightfully serves you a 404 because it has no registered routes with that path.
you should try specifying a new location in you nginx conf:
 location /upload/ {
                    alias /path/on/disk/of/upload;
                    autoindex off;
            }


with nestJS:
using the example from the documentation you linked, edited slightly to server files in the upload directory:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

this will serve static files in the public directory at the root of your site, as if they were at the root of your site. to access them with a /upload/ url, your should put that upload directory inside of the public directory. alternatively, you may simply link sample/9.png and use the upload directory in place of public in the example above.

Thank you, Actually I've configured assets serving in NestJS (https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static), Want to handle it from NestJS. Not intended to handle static serving with Nginx, Need help on this

i've edited my answer. please note that if this is production-critical, i heavily suggest routing through nginx, as it will be considerably faster than any JS solution you can find.

Thank you again. I wanted to place the assets dir outside of the source dir. this is why I've created storage folder where I'll put static assets, logs, caches etc.. I've EDITED the question and added Nginx & NestJS config. Also added projects directory structure to give better context.
